# Reflashing a Playstation 5 firmware chip using a USB EEPROM programmer

Tags: firmware, playstation-5

I have a PS5 that does the BLOD when powering on and instantly turns off. I read that I would need to first find the firmware chip and reflash it with another good one using a USB EEPROM programmer. I wasn't sure which USB programmer I should use or are they all the same? I'm assuming they all just read chip data and write chip data back. Also what is this type of chip called?

I managed to find the firmware chip on the PS5:

[image]

Comment: We can't read the markings on the chip in that photo. Can you tell us the text/numbers (and any distinctive logos) on the chip in question?

Comment: I recall you asking the same question already before, but can't find it. The answer is still same, whatever the memory chip is, you need a programmer that supports it. Looks like generic SPI flash. Flashing a chip is easy, more interesting question is; where do you find any firmware to flash to the chip?

Comment: i was planning to pull it off of another machine.

Comment: At this day and age of computing, the firmware could hold configuration data, such as Ethernet MAC address, or be otherwise tied to the hardware via some sort of ID read off from chips. I highly doubt doing a firmware transplant will work, but do report back here if it does. The next problem is, why would a firmware re-flash fix anything, as why would the firmware chip ever be written or get corrupted? It's likely the hardware that has failed, and firmware can detect that the hardware is not working properly, and thus firmware blinks the LEDs as a sign of not able to continue on broken HW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chip is a [W25Q16JVSNIM](https://www.datasheets.com/en/part-details/w25q16jvsnim-winbond-electronics-82886544) on the PS5. If the PS5 is having the 3 Beeps No Power issue when you plug in the power cable, this is your culprit.

To flash it you need a compatible USB programmer like the CH341 USB programmer and software like AsProgrammer. Take the chip from a confirmed working unit and use the USB programmer and software to read the chip and save it.

I don't think it matters if it's a digital or disc drive version as I have used the digital firmware to fix a disc drive console. Now you have working firmware that you can use to flash the bad chip with.